# emacs: get lexically bound variable value by name

Tags: emacs, elisp

The following does not work with void variable error.  What should `eval` be replaced with to get this to work?

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun foo2 ()
  (let ((b 'lkj))
    (lambda ()
      (eval 'b t))))

(funcall (foo2))
```

`symbol-value` doesn't work either (as documented).

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: To make a long story short, `eval` seems to always evaluate with an empty lexical environment.  Reasons for this are explored in the answers to the other question.

Answer (score 3):

Looking up a variable's value by name is fundamentally incompatible with proper lexical scoping, because proper lexical scoping admits alpha-renaming, i.e. (consistently) renaming a variable should not affect the result.

Of course, if you really must know, you can hack things around in some cases, doing things like:

```
(funcall `(closure ,(nth 1 <someclosure>) () <exp>))
```

which might evaluate `<exp>` in the same scope as the one from where `<someclosure>` comes.  It won't work if `<someclosure>` was byte-compiled (or if I made a mistake).

Comment: This is a good explanation.  It should be in the help text of `eval` and `symbol-value` and the "lexical scoping" section of the manual?